# Neo4j - how to use order by?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH (a:poigroup)
-[r:parameter]->
(b:pointname)-[c:section]->
(d:linepoiset_linepoi)-[actual:actual_value_Z1]->(e:ye04_a1)
Return r,c,actual ORDER BY e.a1_number DESC LIMIT 1
```

It can be work.

But I want to like this

```
MATCH (a:poigroup)-[r:parameter]->
(b:pointname)-[c:section]->
(d:linepoiset_linepoi)-[actual:actual_value_Z1]->
(e:ye04_a1), 
(d:linepoiset_linepoi)-[s:set_value_Z1]->(f:ye04_a131) 
Return r,c,actual,s ORDER BY e.a1_number DESC LIMIT 1
```

But it doesn't work

How to slove it?

Comment: What does `doesn't work` mean? What is the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think ordering does not work intuitively when you `MATCH` multiple paths. You can split the query up like this:

```
MATCH (a:poigroup)-[r:parameter]->
(b:pointname)-[c:section]->
(d:linepoiset_linepoi)-[actual:actual_value_Z1]->
(e:ye04_a1)
WITH r,c,actual,d ORDER BY e.a1_number DESC LIMIT 1
MATCH (d:linepoiset_linepoi)-[s:set_value_Z1]->(f:ye04_a131)
RETURN whatever you want to return
```

This will first `MATCH` from `poigroup` to `ye04_a1` and return only the result with the highest `a1_number` value. You then use the `linepiset_linepo` from that result to `MATCH` to `ye04_a131`.

You can `RETURN` everything from the `WITH` statement.

Comment: But I have new question.
Can you slove it?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36548691/neo4j-how-to-use-limit